# What's the difference between GLPP and LPP

Tags: definition, linear-programming

> $a)$ Express the following optimization problem as a **Linear Programming Problem** (LPP):

$$\text{maximize }3x+3y-30$$$$\text{subject to }|x-2|+|y|\le5$$

> Hint: you will need to express the inequality in another way so there is no absolute signs. For example the inequality $|x|\le3$ is equivalent to the pair of inequilities $x\le3\wedge x\ge-3$

> $b)$ Explain why the following optimization problem is not a LPP:
> $$\text{maximize }3x+3y-30$$$$\text{subject to }|x-2|-|y|\le5$$

---

$a)$ Consider $$|x-2|+|y|\le5$$

$$\Leftrightarrow x-2+|y|\le5\wedge 2-x+|y|\le5$$

$$\Leftrightarrow |y|\le7-x\wedge |y|\le3+x$$

$$\Leftrightarrow (y\le-x+7\wedge y\ge x-7)\wedge(y\le x+3\wedge y\ge-x-3)$$

Basically we have,

$$\text{Maximize }3x+3y-30$$

Subject to,

$$y+x\le7$$$$x-y\le 7$$$$-x+y\le 3$$$$-x-y\le3$$

Which is in the form of **General Linear Programming Problem** (GLPP)

$b)$

Definition(GLPP)

The general linear programming problem can be stated as follows:

Find values of $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ that will maximize or minimize,

$$z=c_1x_1+c_2x_2+\dots+c_nx_n\tag*{(1)}$$

subject to the restrictions,

$$\left.\begin{array}{r}a_{11}x_1+a_{12}x_2+\dots+a_{1n}x_n\le(\ge)(=)b_1\\a_{21}x_1+a_{22}x_2+\dots+a_{2n}x_n\le(\ge)(=)b_2\\\vdots\text{$\qquad\qquad\qquad$}
\\a_{m1}x_1+a_{m2}x_2+\dots+a_{mn}x_n\le(\ge)(=)b_m\end{array}\right\}\tag*{(2)}$$

where in each inequality in $(2)$ one, and only one, of the symbols, $\le,\ge,= $ occurs.

(from [“Elementary Linear Programming With Application" by Bernard Kolman $\cdot$ Robert E. Beck](https://books.google.com/books?id=3iZznGJq4ZMC&source=gbs_book_other_versions))

---

I think there are two reasons that make it not a general linear programming problem:

1. It has costant on left side of inequality which isn't in the form of GLPP.
2. It has absolute value apears in the inequality, that also not allowed in GLPP.

Does this answer part $b)?$

I only found the definition for GLPP from the book, is it the same as LPP $?$

Thanks for your help.

Comment: A GLP(P) is an LP(P). I think a GLP(P) should be distinguished from an LP(P) in standard form. GLP(P) is typically the abbreviation for a generalized LP (which is not an LP).