# Minimization problem with absolute value in objective function

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, absolute-value, visualization

> Consider the following (piecewise linear) minimization problem where $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
>
> $$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & |x| + y\\ \text{subject to} & x + y = 2\\ & x \le 2\end{array}$$
>
> Convert this into a linear program and solve it graphically.

---

My attempts (Updated)

Since $x,y$ are unconstrained

Let $x=x^++x^-,y=y^++y^-$

minimize $$z=x^++x^-+y^++y^-$$

subject to $$x^++x^-+y^++y^-=2$$ $$x^++x^-+s=2$$ $$x^+,x^-,y^+,y^-,s\ge0$$

That blue line is the objective function, and black region are union of all constraints

[image]

Now we take the intersection of all the constraints to get the region of feasible solution

[image]

Not hard to see, when $z=2$ the intersection of the objective function and that black line is all the optimal solution.

[image]

In another words, any convex combinations of $(0,2)$ and $(2,0)$ is a optimal solution.

---

See more detail about the definition of GLPP in this post.

[What's the difference between GLPP and LPP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3378740)

Is my answer correct$?$ And does LPP require all the constraints have same signs in $\{\ge,\le,=\}?$is it yet a form of LPP?

Is it ok to have unconstrained varibles in LPP $?$

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only part of the original problem that violates linearity is the absolute value in the objective.  Rewrite $x$ as $x^+ - x^-$ with $x^+ \ge 0$ and $x^- \ge 0$.  Then replace $|x|$ with $x^+ + x^-$.  Explicitly, the resulting LP is:
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} & x^+ + x^- + y &\\
&\text{subject to} & x^+ - x^- + y &= 2\\
&&x^+ - x^- &\le 2 \\
&&x^+ \ge 0, x^- \ge 0, y \text{ free} \\
\end{align}
If you want to solve it graphically, you can reduce to two variables by eliminating $y$, yielding:
\begin{align}
&\text{minimize} & 2x^- + 2 &\\
&\text{subject to} &x^+ - x^- &\le 2 \\
&&x^+ \ge 0, x^- \ge 0 \\
\end{align}
In this form, it is clear that optimality requires $x^- = 0$, and the constraints then reduce to simple bounds $0 \le x^+ \le 2$.  Any such $x^+$ is optimal, with $z=2$.  You can then recover $(x,y)$ as $(x^+,2-x^+)$.

Comment: Let $x=x^++x^-,y=y^++y^-$

minimize $$z=x^++x^-+y^++y^-$$

subject to $$x^++x^-+y^++y^-=2$$ $$x^++x^-+s=2$$ $$x^+,x^-,y^+,y^-,s\ge0$$

Like this $?$

Comment: Is it ok to have unconstrained varibles in LPP $?$

Comment: Yes, free variables are fine, but you should have $x^+ - x^-$ instead of $x^+ + x^-$ in the constraints.  Also, there is no reason to introduce $y^+$, $y^-$, or $s$.  See my updated answer.